# Get names of XElements

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, xelement

I'm parsing xml in the app for windows phone.
My XML Looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<people>
    <person name="Kurt Cobain">
      <overall>
  
      </overall>
      <childhood>
  
      </childhood>
      <youth>
  
      </youth>
  
     <picture1>
  
      </picture1>
    </person>
  
</people>
```

I should get the names of the element of the person node(overall, childhood, youth etc) because for each person node they will be different.
Here is my code so far,but the query results in null:

```
XDocument loadedXml = XDocument.Load("people.xml");

                    var data = from query in loadedXml.Descendants("person")
                               where ((query.Attribute("name").Value as string).Equals("Kurt Cobain"))
                               select query.Elements();

                    
                     string test = "";
                     foreach (var item in data)
                     {
                         
                             test + = (item as XElement).Name.LocalName;
                         
                     }
                     MessageBox.Show(test);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `.Elements()` from your linq.

```
var data = from query in loadedXml.Descendants("person") 
           where ((query.Attribute("name").Value as string).Equals("Kurt Cobain")) 
           select query;
```

Comment: And the foreach loop should be like this: foreach (var item in data)
                    {

                        XElement el = (item as XElement);
                        foreach(var t in el.Elements())
                        {
                            test += (t as XElement).Name.LocalName;
                        }
                    }

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = from item in loadedXml.Descendants("person")
                   where ((item.Attribute("name").Value as string).Equals("Kurt Cobain"))
                   select item;

string test = "";
foreach (var item in data)
   test += item.Attribute("name").Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

I see your trying to use XElement in one part of your code, The other suggestions should work, but you can also do the following:

```
  XElement loadedXml = XElement.Load("people.xml");

  string test = "";

  foreach (var item in loadedXml.XPathSelectElements("person[@name='Kurt Cobain']"))
  {
  test += item.Attribute("name").Value;
  }
```

Or you can make do it like so (it makes it hard to read however).

```
 XElement loadedXml = XElement.Load("people.xml");

 string test = loadedXml.XPathSelectElements("person[@name='Kurt Cobain']").Aggregate("", (current, item) => current + item.Attribute("name").Value);
```